# C# - Member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
Hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<GunShot>().slots[0] = Inventory.inventory[Inventory.SlotSelected];
```

Обращаюсь к другому скрипту, подключенному к другому объекту, но выдает такую ошибку:

> *Member 'GunShot.slots' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead*

Что надо сделать?

Comment: вы пытаетесь обратиться к статической переменной используя ссылку. Я так понимаю что ваше поле slots как раз статическое, да ?

Comment: Да, понял. Помню очень давно использовал статические поля для осуществления с ними действий с других скриптов, и сейчас что-то напутал, спасибо

Comment: @Andrey так может ответом?

Comment: Спасибо добрый чел.
Годы идут, а твой ответ все еще помогает нуждающимся ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема в том что происходит обращение к статическому полю используя ссылку. Статические поля доступны на уровне класса и поэтому не правильно обращаться к ним на уровне объекта.
Пример

```
ClassWithStaticField.StaticField - правильно

ClassWithStaticField instance = new ClassWithStaticField();
instance.StaticField - неправильно
```